# Need to Group php array with same keys

Tags: php

Hii I need help in grouping array where i have this sort of array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => rose
            [price] => 1
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => daisy
        [price] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => orchid
        [price] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => rose
        [price] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => daisy
        [price] => 3
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => orchid
        [price] => 1
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => rose
        [price] => 2
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => daisy
        [price] => 3
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [name] => orchid
        [price] => 2
    )

)
```

and i want it to be like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => rose
                    [price] => 1
                )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => daisy
                [price] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => orchid
                [price] => 1
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => rose
                [price] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => daisy
                [price] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => orchid
                [price] => 2
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => rose
                [price] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => daisy
                [price] => 3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => orchid
                [price] => 3
            )

    )

 )
```

I mean want to group them where same "price" value occurs . You can better understand them from given arrays .

Comment: Have you tried anything? A loop and setting the price as index might help.

Comment: Yes i tried some, but didn't help

Comment: If you have solution to it, that can be much helpful .

Comment: @RimpyKakeyalia  no matter your code worked or not. Always put what you have tried so for

Answer (score 1):

```
$group = array();

foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    $group[$value['price']][] = $value;
}

var_dump($group);
```